"There is not enough usable space for this operation" when adding mirror to volume in Windows Server
I'm trying to mirror Windows volume between two disks, but it won't let me convert disks to dynamic until I delete Recovery partition.
DISKPART> list disk

  Disk ###  Status         Size     Free     Dyn  Gpt
  --------  -------------  -------  -------  ---  ---
  Disk 0    Online           40 GB  1024 KB
  Disk 1    Online           40 GB    39 GB

DISKPART> select disk 0

Disk 0 is now the selected disk.

DISKPART> list partition

  Partition ###  Type              Size     Offset
  -------------  ----------------  -------  -------
  Partition 1    Primary            100 MB  1024 KB
  Partition 2    Primary             39 GB   101 MB
  Partition 3    Recovery           724 MB    39 GB

DISKPART> convert dynamic

Virtual Disk Service error:
There is not enough usable space for this operation.

This works fine with GPT, but with MBR There is not enough usable space for this operation. Which is a lie, because I reinstalled Windows with 1GB unallocated space at the end, and it didn't help:
Same error with 1GB of unallocated space at the end
Then I tried the solution from here:

Capture the image of Recovery partition with dism
Disable ReAgentC with reagentc /disable
Delete Recovery partition
Convert disks to dynamic and create my mirror
Create a simple volume for Recovery, format as NTFS, assign letter R
Apply Recovery image to new volume with dism
Set the new location of WinRE with reagentc /setreimage /path R:\Recovery\WindowsRE
Enable ReAgentC with reagentc /enable

Last two steps is where I get a new problem:
>reagentc /setreimage /path R:\Recovery\WindowsRE
Directory set to:

REAGENTC.EXE: Operation Successful.


>reagentc /enable
REAGENTC.EXE: The Windows RE image was not found.

Here is dir of R:\Recovery\WindowsRE to confirm that it has Winre.wim:
>dir R:\Recovery\WindowsRE /a

 Directory of R:\Recovery\WindowsRE

10/17/2024  12:31 AM    <DIR>          .
10/17/2024  10:31 AM    <DIR>          ..
05/08/2021  01:14 AM         3,170,304 boot.sdi
10/17/2024  12:31 AM             1,117 ReAgent.xml
09/05/2024  03:54 PM       618,384,178 Winre.wim
               3 File(s)    621,555,599 bytes
               2 Dir(s)     121,339,904 bytes free

So the question is, is it possible to mirror Windows volume and have Recovery partition as well?

You also didn’t run create partition primary id=27 I didn’t even think WS2022 supported MBR. The solution you used was incomplete and outdated. While not a direct answer to your question this answer has the correct steps.

There is a second solution create the mirror then create the WinRE partition.

@Ramhound Dynamic disks are required to make a mirror volume to host OS. It's not possible to use Storage Space here and I'm not aware of any other method.
It's not possible to change types in dynamic disk, and id=27 is used to make partition hidden and avoid user mistakes anyway, so I doubt it's causing issues.
I did try to create WinRE partition after mirror, it didn't work (explanation is in the question). Also your link points to my question, could you edit it?

Here is the correct link, but if you have already attempted to setup the dynamic mirroring then create the WinRE, I don't think the slight differences in how you create the WinRE will matter to be honest.

Decided to post an answer myself since I did figure this out. Maybe helps someone out in the future.
The steps to recreate Windows RE partition were almost complete, all I had to do is retain the Recovery volume in diskpart between steps 6 and 7. Also dism was not required, I used xcopy command instead from this doc.
The retain command "Prepares an existing simple dynamic volume for use as a boot or system volume". No wonder it didn't work before.
After that, reagentc /setreimage ... and reagentc /enable worked as expected, and I was able to boot into Windows RE without any problem.
